# Why do these two C++ statements give two different locations in memory

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, logic

With the following code, two different addresses are printed out. Can anyone explain why? I'm not the most proficient with pointers but I presumed that they would give the same address.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    float (*arrayName)[2][4][4];

    auto address1 = (**arrayName)[1]; // 0x10
    auto address2 = (*arrayName)[1][0]; // 0x40
    std::cout << "Address1: " << address1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address2: " << address2 << std::endl;
}
```

0x40 is the address I'm looking for. Just don't understand why I get two different answers.

I was expecting both to give me an answer of 0x40 however one doesn't. Tried this code on an online C++ compiler and both gave me the address of 0x10. However on my development RHEL7 vm, I get 0x10 and the expected 0x40 address.

Comment: Because of *undefined behavior*... The variable `arrayName` is a pointer, but you never make it point anywhere. Therefore its contents, its value, will be *indeterminate*. And using indeterminate values in any way in C++ leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: `x[a]` is exactly equivalent to `*(x+ a)`. What `x+a` actually does depends on the types of `x` and `a` and `*arrayName` has different type than `**arrayName`. And of course for dereference, `*`, you need a valid pointer

Comment: why do you need to do this? You are just one step away from being a [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) (or one step beyond?). I would argue that already a `float[2][4][4]` should be reconsidered

Comment: The output of this code could be anything. gccs sanitizer is quite clear on what the issue is: https://godbolt.org/z/8n48W4ojh

Comment: please fix your typos. Missing `;` and you are printing `address1` twice

Comment: Those are pretty strange addresses to expect. Please explain why you are expecting them. (And read about the [mcve].)

Comment: I added some missing pieces. if you have more please update. It makes quite some difference whether `arrayName` is initialized or not

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for what's really going on, please learn that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`.

From that it follows that `p[0]` must be equal to `*(p + 0)` which of course is equal to `*(p)` which is the same as `*p`.

And from that we can learn that `*arrayName` is the same as `arrayName[0]`, from which follows that `**arrayName` is `arrayName[0][0]`.

With this information it's easy to see that `(*arrayName)[1][0]` is different from `(**arrayName)[1]`:

- `(*arrayName)[1][0]` is the same as `arrayName[0][1][0]`.
- `(**arrayName)[1]` is the same as `arrayName[0][0][1]`.

But remember, because `arrayName` isn't assigned or initialized with a specific pointer, it can't be dereferenced.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense to me now :)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `*x` and `(x)[0]` are interchangeable, so let us convert everything to one form:

```
(**arrayName)[1] = (*(arrayName[0]))[1] = arrayName[0][0][1]
(*arrayName)[1][0] = (arrayName[0])[1][0] = arrayName[0][1][0]
```

These two expressions are clearly different.